# Accessing class objects across rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

Forgive me if this has already been answered somewhere because I could not find it.

I'm trying to include a class I've written in Rails 3 under the lib directory so that my controllers may access the methods.

The class is in this directory, specifically: lib/assets, and it's called Ducksboard.

I'm attempting to include this in my application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Ducksboard
```

But I keep getting a routing error like this

> uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Ducksboard

I've even updated the application config file so that it searches in the library for assets

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Is there a better way to create classes and access them across my application? This doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged asset-pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you put it in lib/**assets**? You know what assets are used for in Rails, right?

Anyway, you need to add an initializer in config/initializers

```
require_dependency 'assets/ducksboard'
```

Comment: I was reading this, under Asset organization: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html , so I may have misinterpreted it. Given that's the wrong design, where in a Rails application should I be putting new classes?

Comment: Put the classes/files in `lib`.

Comment: Exactly. Put it there and add an initializer as per my answer. When doing the require do __not__ add lib/ to the path (provide only the path after lib/). E.g. require_dependency 'ducksboard' when you have it in lib/ducksboard.rb.